# Spark SQL : can I get total map reduce steps when spark runs it's sql?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, apache-spark-sql

When I run

```
spark.sql("select bill_no, count(icode) from bigmart.o_sales group by bill_no").explain(true);
```

I get only this much explaination

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Aggregate ['bill_no], ['bill_no AS bill#0, 'count('icode) AS icode#1]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation `bigmart`.`o_sales`

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
bill: string, icode: bigint
Aggregate [bill_no#15], [bill_no#15 AS bill#0, count(icode#12) AS icode#1L]
+- MetastoreRelation bigmart, o_sales

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [bill_no#15], [bill_no#15 AS bill#0, count(icode#12) AS icode#1L]
+- Project [icode#12, bill_no#15]
   +- MetastoreRelation bigmart, o_sales

== Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[bill_no#15], functions=[count(icode#12)], output=[bill#0, icode#1L])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(bill_no#15, 200)
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[bill_no#15], functions=[partial_count(icode#12)], output=[bill_no#15, count#19L])
      +- HiveTableScan [icode#12, bill_no#15], MetastoreRelation bigmart, o_sales
```

Is it all `explain()` can offer? or is there other methods that gives more details. I want to learn how map and reduce is done behind the scene by spark.